# How to Zero-pad Float Point Numbers in Javascript and with limit on max number of digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, underscore.js

How can a float be right padded with zeros such that

1. Number of digits after padding is 7
2. Zeros are padded to the right of the decimal point `.`
3. Numbers with more than 7 digits are truncated from the right

`.toFixed(6)` ignores the number of digits before the decimal point `.`.

**Input**

```
9.123
9.123456
6.12345678
100.1
```

**Output**

```
9.123000
9.123450
6.123456
100.1000    // truncated from the right
```

Comment: You could adjust the number you pass to `.toFixed` by the number of digits before the decimal point.

Comment: Looks not to hard - did you try sth?

Comment: What if 100,000,000 ?

Comment: @wared The number is not expected to hit 100,000,000. If it does, I guess an `if` statement will convert it to exponentil form 1.0E8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n.toFixed(5).substring(0, 7)
```

It will fail miserably for anything 100000 or greater.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the result is a string :

```
var n = 9.123 + '';
if (n.length < 8) {
    n += new Array(9 - n.length).join('0');
} else if (n.length > 8) {
    n = n.slice(0, 8);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is me trying to be clever :

```
Number.prototype.toTotallyFixed = function(n) {
    var s = this.toString(), a = (s + (s.indexOf('.') != -1 ? '' : '.0')).split('.');
    return a[0].length > n ? s.slice(0,n) : a[0] + (+('.'+a[1])).toFixed(n - (a[0].length-1)).slice(1);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CjruL/5/)